# CPU spikes to 100% when using openSSH for windows

Tags: windows, openssh

I am using openSSH for windows (OpenSSH 7.1p1-1). I noticed that after few days that the sshd.exe processes are at the range of 20% cpu the spike to 100% utilization all taken by the processes. i googled the issue and looked here and found one answer saying that when running openSSH along with an antivirus they can compete for resources, the thing is i do not have anti virus on this windows machine

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: what is going on in logs? How many sshd precesses do you see there?

Comment: You can download [Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) suite to see what's going on with the processes, specifically you can check [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) to check IO operations etc. and [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer) for process state such as threads etc.

Comment: I would run:`procdump -ma processname` (https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) to get 2 or 3 dumps when it has the issue. You can get procdump to do this for you with switches if needed. Then open them in Windbg (There is a Store app, but I would set the Windows SDK for your platform and install the Debugging Tools).  Run `!runaway` against the dumps to find the busy threads. Then look at the stacks of these threads to try and glean what they are doing, which modules are involved etc..  I would suggest performing the following on a few dumps to see if it's consistent.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows 10 you could try installing Windows's Official OpenSSH Client (and server too if you'd like remote access to Windows over SSH).

From *Control Panel* -> *Apps*, in *Apps & Features* tab, click on *Manage Optional Features* and add *OpenSSH Client*.

You might have to uninstall the other client, run ssh.exe using full path or adjust your %Path% to run the correct version. Once installed Windows's version of ssh.exe should be installed in `%windir%\System32\OpenSSH\` with this directory added to your %Path%.

Answer (score 0):

If you have had it running for a very long time (or had too many bad connection attempts) I've noticed it'll start to experience issues.

Just see about opening up port 22 and making sure defender isn't blocking it.  Make sure you stop the service and "taskkill /IM "sshd.exe" /F"
then see if that helps at all.